# How to keep VSCode from spreading information on multiple lines in React? (formatting)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tabs, formatting, prettier

I have a following code in React which I want to keep in a single line shown below:

```
<Title level={2} className="heading">Global Crypto Stats</Title>
```

However, on saving my file I get a code spread on multiple lines like that:

```
<Title level={2} className="heading">
    Global Crypto Stats
  </Title>
```

I'm not sure whether it is prettier or VSCode on safe function. Can't seem to find it. This isn't "Toggle Word Wrap" (Alt+Z) function.

Answer (score 1):

Select the lines you want to join and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>J</kbd> on Mac. Or Press <kbd>F1</kbd> and "Join Lines"

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful but it changes back to multiple lines on save.

Comment: Hmm, it works on my system .. VScode even with prettier installed. It might be your prettier settings or perhaps another plugin intervening with the formatting on save

Answer (score 1):

go to `file>preferences>settings` on top, search `format on save` and remove the tic that says `Edit:format on save`

Comment: Is it possible to keep formatting on save, but keep it a single liner? Formatting helps me with indentation, so I kind of want to keep it. I've seen people online with this option, but can't seem to find the appropriate option.

Comment: Not sure if it does the trick for you, but in the same menu you can find format on save mode ,change if from file to modifications. This way , only the code hat you are changing will be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you have code format extensions installed, which formate your code in this way, you may have "Prettier" installed or some other extensions.
uninstall or disable those extensions, your problem will be solved.